# Reverse connection to remote database

Tags: routing, port-forwarding, openvpn, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I have a very large database on my home server. But my ISP doesn't allow me a port forward. Is there a way to reverse the connection from my web hosting server to my home database server which doesn't have a static IP address?

Comment: Can you ssh from home to the web hosting server? If so, you can ssh from home to the webserver, and bind your home port to a port on localhost of your webserver. Then your web server has access to your home database. Is this an option? You would use the -R option to "push" your home port to the server.

Comment: @fundagain Yes, I can. But using putty is okay? Or can you give me clear instructions, please?

Comment: Here is the normal ssh which would forward home 127.0.0.1:4321 to server 127.0.0.1:14321 for example: ssh -fNT -R 4321:localhost:14321 me@webserver

Comment: It can definately be done with putty: see https://www.ccsl.carleton.ca/~falaca/comp4108_w17/ssh_putty/index.html (you want remote not local).

Comment: @fundagain yes it works. Thanks man

Comment: Pleasure, Ssh is a great hacking tool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is ssh from home to your server and use ssh port forwarding to "push" your home database port (say 4321 on 127.0.0.1) to the server and bind it to the server 127.0.0.1 on a port of your choice (possibly also 4321, but you could chose 14321 for example).

You need to use remote port forwarding and not local port forwarding.

With an ssh client you would use `ssh -R 4321:localhost:14321` or `ssh -fNT -R 4321:localhost:14321` if you with to forward but detach.

Now port 14321 on the localhost of the server behaves as port 4321 on localhost of your home machine.

With Putty you will need to go to Connection | SSH | Tunnels but use the Remote options not the Local options.